# When default PositionIndicator on Here Map has green or grey color. What does the color depend on?

Tags: here-api

PositioningManager is started and gets position updates.

`PositioningManager.getInstance().start(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK_INDOOR)`

PositionIndicator is set to visible.
`positionIndicator.isVisible = true`

When I start app positionIndicator sometimes has green, and sometimes grey color. Can anyone explain that. 
I can not find any information in HERE Android SDK.

Thanks

Comment: Color of that icon depends on current location status. For example if PositioningManager.getLocationStatus() is either OUT_OF_SERVICE or TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE then grey color will be active, if status == AVAILABLE then icon will be green.

Answer (score 0):

Color of that icon depends on current location status. For example if `PositioningManager.getLocationStatus()` is either `OUT_OF_SERVICE` or `TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE` then grey color will be active, if `status == AVAILABLE` then icon will be green.